# open c project in vs code on Mac

Tags: c, windows, macos, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2022

I have a c project that I wrote in visual studio 2022 on windows. now I'm trying to open this project on my MacBook (if it makes any difference I'm using 2019 intel MBA). I use vs code on my MBA. the project has .h and .c files and when I try to debug the project I have this errors:

**ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64**
**clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1**

and

**Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64**

in the project folder there is only x64 debug folder. maybe I need to configure the file when I save it in vs 2022?

Comment: You probably have Windows specific code. You'll need to edit it for MacOS or whatever OS you're using.

Comment: you can use cmake to rebuild your project

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.